# Linq select where items exists in list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

this should be easy, but I can't make it Work.

I have a list(of T) and a linq to sql Query. I want to select all records where a specific key in the Query is also to find in the list

So I do this:

```
Public Class myChekList
   Public Property custNo As String
   Public Property No As String
 End Class

 '''fill a list object myChkLst with items      

  Dim query = From a In db.MyTable.Where(myChkLst(Function(f) f.No).Contains(a.No))
```

But this is terrible wrong. Can anybody help me?

Best regards.

Comment: Why is it "terribly wrong"?

Comment: [LINQ Query Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688084.aspx), [101 Visual Basic LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested but something like this:

```
 Dim query = db.MyTable.Where(Function(f) myChkLst.Select(Function(c) c.No).Contains(f.No))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .any either

```
 Dim query = From a In db.MyTable.Where(Function(f) myChkLst.any(function(c) c.No = f.no)))
```

Comment: Seems OP needs `Contains` not `=`

Comment: @huMptyduMpty This is equivalent in terms of functionality, it's just more verbose syntax for doing it.

Comment: As it seems that the list has more than one field either , it should be select/contains or any.(I think)

Comment: Using your example with 'any' gave me an exception: 'Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator'

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry, I always used this method after retrieving list from db, I searched and saw that you are right. The only way to do it directly from your tables is using Contains.